# Dynamic Programming Algorithm similar to Knapsack Java Code

Tags: java, algorithm, iteration, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

A mission-critical production system has n stages that have to be performed sequentially; stage i is performed by machine M_i.

Each machine M_i has a probability r_i of functioning reliably and a probability 1-r_i of failing (and the failures are independent). Therefore, if we implement each stage with a single machine, the probability that the whole system works is r_1,r_2,...,r_n. To improve this probability we add redundancy, by having m_i copies of the machine M_i that performs stage i.

The probability that all m_i copies fail simultaneously is only (1-r_i)^(m_i), so the probability that stage i is completed correctly is 1-(1-r_i)^(mi) and the probability that the whole system works is prod(i=1,n){1-(1-r_i)^(m_i)}.

Each machine M_i has a cost c_i, and there is a total budget B to buy machines. (Assume that B and c_i are positive integers.) Write the algorithm in java code that given probabilities r_1,...,r_n, the costs c_1,...,c_n, and the budget B, finds the redundancies m_1,...,m_n that are within the available budget and that maximize the probability that the system works correctly (determine the maximum reliability achievable). Also, show how many machines of each type achieve that reliability bound within the budget.

So I read in a file that gives me the total budget allowed, followed by the number of machines, and then for each machine I read in the cost and the reliability. I store the cost and and reliability into two linked list (not sure if this is best).

```
  try {
            BufferedReader newFileBuffer = new BufferedReader(new     FileReader(inputFile));
            budget = Integer.parseInt(newFileBuffer.readLine()); 
            numberOfMachines = Integer.parseInt(newFileBuffer.readLine()); 
            while ((fileLine  = newFileBuffer.readLine()) != null) 
            {       
                line = fileLine.split(" ");

                try 
                {
                    cost.add(Integer.parseInt(line[0]));
                    totalCostOfOneEach += Integer.parseInt(line[0]); 
                    reliability.add(Float.parseFloat(line[1]));
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};

            }
            newFileBuffer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

From there I know that one of each machine must be used once so I subtract the budget by the total amount it cost for one of each machine (totalCostOfOneEach), this gives me left over budget or the redundancy budget if you will.

```
bRedundent = (budget - totalCostOfOneEach);
```

Now is where I am stuck, I am lost on what to loop over to find the solution. I have researched and found this [solution](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/6734/46973) but I do not understand the line

```
Pr(b,j)=max{Pr(b-c_j*k, j-1)*(1-(1-r_j)^k}
```

So what I do know is I have created a double array and I initialize the arrays as so:

```
double[][] finalRel = new double[numberOfMachines][bRedundent]; 
for (int j = 0; j < numberOfMachines; j++)
{
    finalRel[0][j] = 0; 
}

for (int b = 1; b < budget; b++)
{
    finalRel[b][1] = reliability.get(0); 
}
```

Now is where I am stuck, I believe I should loop on the number of machine and then the cost but this is not working and I know I need incorporate the budget somehow. So this is what I currently have that does not work at all:

```
for (int i = 1; i < numberOfMachines; i++)
{
    for (int c = cost.get(i); c < budget; c++)
    {
        finalRel[i][c] = Math.min(finalRel[i-1][c], finalRel[i-1][c - cost.get(numberOfMachines)]*(l));
    }   
}
```

I know the subproblem is denoted finalRel[i, b], the most reliable configuration of machines 1, 2, . . . , i (at least one of each machine) available within budget b. The desired answer will be finalRel[n, B].

And the recurrence  if we are under budget, we return reliability 0 (meaning not possible). If we are out of budget (b = 0), but still need to buy machines (i > 0),we return 0 (assume all ci > 0). If i = 0, we have have no machines that we have to buy, so reliability is 1 (if it were 0, then everything would get multiplied by 0, which is no good). If there is budget left (b > 0) and machines left to buy (i > 0), we try all possibilities m of machines of type i to buy - we have to buy at least m ≥ 1, and up to m ≤ b ≤ floor(b/c_i) ≤ b ≤ B, of them. In each case, the remaining budget will be b − m · c_i. The best reliability for machines 1, . . . , i − 1 will be REL[i − 1, b − m · ci], which needs to be multiplied by the contribution of the m copies of M_i, (1 − (1 − ri)^m) or summarized [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHeD8.png).

I realize this a lot of information but I have been stuck for a while now so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can work with a simpler recurrence than that. For `i = 0, ..., n` and `b = 0, ..., B`, we let `R(i, b)` be the maximum reliability of the sub-pipeline from stage `1` to stage `i` given budget `B`. The base cases are

```
For b = 0, ..., B,
  R(0, b) = 1,
```

since the empty pipeline never fails and costs nothing. Thereafter we have the linked recurrence, which I have rewritten slightly for clarity:

```
For i = 1, ..., n,
  For b = 0, ..., B,
    R(i, b) = max {R(i-1, b - k*c_i) * (1 - (1-r_i)^k)
                   for k = 1, ..., floor(b/c_i)},
```

where `k` is the number of stage `i` machines that we're considering buying (defining `0^0 = 1` in case machines can be perfectly reliable; you should compute the power yourself and then strength-reduce to a multiplication, which solves this issue and improves performance). The factor `(1 - (1-r_i)^k)` is the reliability of a stage `i` with `k` machines. The factor `R(i-1, b - k*c_i)` is the maximum reliability of the previous stages given the residual budget. The limit `floor(b/c_i)` is the maximum number of stage `i` machines that cost at most `b` in total.

Comment: I don't understand this line:
 `R(i, b) = max{R(i-1, b - k*c_i) * (1 - (1-r_i)^k) for k = 0, ..., floor(b/c_i)}`
How is this suppose to work, you're taking the max between a double array and a floor loop which is defining what k is but we are trying to use it before it is defined in the max function? If the for loop is suppose to be included in the max function I don't see how it would return a double array? Sorry I'm struggling with this logic.

Comment: is the way to accomplish this in java is use ImmutableSet.Builder? http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.Builder.html

Comment: @BillLogger No, replace it with a loop.

Comment: I can't put new lines in the comment so the format is ugly.

Comment: That is what I originally thought but is still not working correctly or how I am expecting. Not sure what I am doing wrong:  
`numberOfMachines = 8;
  budget = 1000; 
  for (int i = 1; i < numberOfMachines; i++)
  {
   for (int b = 0; b < budget; b++)
   {
    for (int k = 0; k < (Math.floor(b/cost.get(i))); k++)
    {
     finalRel[i][b] = Math.max(finalRel[i-1][b], (finalRel[i-1][b-cost.get(i)*k] * (1-Math.pow((1-reliability.get(i)),k))));
    }
   }
  }
  double x = finalRel[numberOfMachines-1][budget-1]; 
  System.out.println(x);
 }
}`

Comment: Instead of using the max function I use a greater than check which is finally giving me a different number that 0: `for (int k = 0; k < (Math.floor(b/cost.get(i))); k++)
    {
     double temp = finalRel[i-1][b-k*cost.get(i)]; 
     double expon = Math.pow((1-reliability.get(i)),k); 
     double temp1 = (1-expon); 
     if (finalRel[i][b] < temp * temp1)
     {
      finalRel[i][b] = temp * temp1;
     }
    }`
But it is still not correct.

Comment: Don't we need at least 1 machine per stage? How are we allowing k to be 0?